# Index sizes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am just starting to investigate optimization for my MySQL database. From what I'm reading, indexing seems like a good idea - so I am wanting to create an index on one of my `VARCHAR` columns, on a table using the `MyISAM` engine.

From what I'm reading, I understand that an index is limited to a size of 1,000 bytes. A `VARCHAR` character is 3 bytes in size, though. Does that mean that if I want to index a `VARCHAR` column with 50 rows, I need an index prefix of 6 characters? (1,000 bytes / 50 rows / 3 bytes per character = 6.66)

If so, that seems a little comiplicated - which is why I'm questioning my understanding. It seems pretty odd that you would only be able to index 333 rows in a `VARCHAR` column, using a prefix of 1 character.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From what I've read, I understand that an index is limited to a size of 1000 bytes.

Index **key** length is limited to `1000` bytes in `MyISAM`, `767` bytes in `InnoDB` (per column).

This means that you cannot index a single `UTF8` column more than `333` characters long in a `MyISAM` table (when calculating the max index size, `MySQL` assumes `3` bytes per character, though actual length may be much smaller)

You can create as many indexed records as you need.

Comment: Oh, so the 1000 bytes restriction only applies to the column name?

Comment: @Tommy: it applies to the maximum amount of characters you can store in an indexed column of a single record.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it a little. So each record in the column I want to index can have 333 characters. What's the reason of using index prefix with less than 333 characters then? The example in mysql reference uses a prefix of 10 characters.

Comment: @Tommy: it's faster. The index is shrunk in size and more records can fit into a single page. Sometimes `10` characters is enough to narrow down the search to a record or two which can be further filtered with a pure comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think its meant the varchar width. If the index max size is 1000 bytes and a varchar is 3 bytes long then the max indexable size would be 1000/3.